# Objectify: How does one use the @Container annotation?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, data-modeling, objectify

The following (abstracted) code gives a StackOverflow error, I assume due to recursive referencing between Team and Member (Team contains Member, which contains Team, etc).

```
@Entity public class Team {
  @Id public String id;
  public List<Member> members;

  public Team() {
    this.id = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
  }
}


public class Member {
  @Container Team team; //removing this line prevents error, but then how to reference this member's team?

  public Member() {}
}
```

How does one set up the annotations for this relationship properly, so that a team has references to its members, and each member has a reference to its team?

Answer (score 0):

@Container causes an embedded entity to be populated with the referenced entity. If you do what you have above, when you load one of `Team` or `Member`, it will load the other as an embedded entity in it, which then load the former again inside it -> Obviously this is an infinite recursion of Teams and Members all the way to an overflow.

Assuming a `Member` can only be on one team. perhaps you are better setting `Team` to be a `@Parent` (Teams contain members, a member is part of a team). Keep in mind this means you'll have a sustained 1 write per second limit, although you can burst higher for short durations.

Comment: Thank you. Could you show an example of how to properly use the @Container annotation?